# 3D image gallery with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

Anyone does a jquery plugin that support create 3d gallery as http://www.webpsilon.com/wordpress-plugins/matrix-gallery/

Comment: Not exactly same but its nice http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/06/3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: I don't think that there is a exact plugin that does that for you, since the plugin you provided seems to use flash.

Comment: @EvilP:Yep.The plugin that I provided use flash but I want to find other jquery that can do it.

Comment: Okay, but there is no 1:1 solution in jquery. Maybe you could develop some on your own or just google 3d image gallery jquery !

Comment: @arunes: thank you so much but I want to find a plugin that can move smoothly like this,not move only one image per time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3D Carousel plugin, it's very useful in your case
check this link [3D Carousel](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)